# Permission Denied while importing/Deleting keys in GNUpg

Tags: java

I am getting the below error while importing keys to key ring/deleting from key ring.

> gpg: renaming `c:\gnupg\pubring.gpg' to`c:\gnupg\pubring.bak' failed:
>   Permission denied

How to change permission?Please help..

Comment: What version of GPG do you use?

Comment: I am Using Gpg4win 2.3.3